# Rolling through an array with jQuery, HTML & JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to print this array: `photolist` into my DIV called: `fotolist`, but don’t know how to. I want to print the array after it loops through both completely. How do I do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="jquery-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function() {
    API_KEY = 'YOURAPIKEY'; //INSERT API KEY
    USER_ID = '22694125@N02'; //ENTER USER ID

    var photolist = [];

    $.getJSON('https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.getPhotos&api_key=' + API_KEY + '&user_id=' + USER_ID + '&format=json&jsoncallback=?', function(rest) {

        var numPhotos = rest.photos.pages;

        for (var u =0; u < numPhotos; u++) {    
            $.getJSON('https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.getPhotos&api_key=' + API_KEY + '&user_id=' + USER_ID + '&format=json&jsoncallback=?&pages=' + u, function(results) {
                for (var m =0; m < results.photos.total; m++) {
                    photolist.push("https://www.flickr.com/" + results.photos.photo[m].owner + "/" + results.photos.photo[m].id);


                }      
            });
        }    
    }); 
});
  </script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="fotolist">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a more useful title

Comment: You can use `$('#fotolist').html(`<your text goes here>`);` for sending an html entry inside the fotolist. (When I say html, it can be both html and text)

Comment: @user3205630 here is an example: http://jsbin.com/lalinino/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

Use `.append` if you want to push content into an already existing div. Make sure targetDiv is declared outside the $.getJSON call.

```
    var targetDiv = $('#printDiv');

    for (var m =0; m < results.photos.total; m++) 
    {
    targetDiv.append("https://www.flickr.com/" + 
results.photos.photo[m].owner + "/" + results.photos.photo[m].id);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick.

a. Here is a one liner assuming array contains only links:

```
$("#fotolist").append(photolist.join(" </br> "));
```

`</br>` is present to break the lines, if you don't want to break line, just remove that part

b. Paste the code after the for loop.

```
$.each(photolist, function(){
   $("#fotolist").append(this);
});
```

c. Though the above method will work, we are refreshing the DOM often.

So you need to create a DOM fragment and add all text/html to it and then append it to DOM for performance reasons.

```
var html = "";

$.each(photolist, function(){
         html +=this;
    });
$("#fotolist").append(html);
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsbin.com/lalinino/1/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

1. Push items to an array
2. Join the items in the array
3. `.append()` the items to your target

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PMZ4y/)**

jQuery:

```
var myList = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    myList.push('<li>');
    myList.push('My name is Agent 00' + i);
    myList.push('</li>');
}

$("#target").append(myList.join(''));
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="target"></ul>
```